# Svelte Kit SSG with dynamic routes on Github Pages

Tags: svelte, github-pages, sveltekit

These are the steps I followed to deploy my Svelte website to GitHub Pages:

```bash
npm create svelte@latest svelte-test
cd svelte-test
pnpm i
pnpm i -D @sveltejs/adapter-static
```

then proceeded to create an empty *.nojekyll* file in the *static* folder and a *+layout.ts* file inside of *src/routes* with the following content:

```
export const prerender = true;
```

then I modified the *svelte.config.js* file as follows:

```js
import adapter from '@sveltejs/adapter-static';
import { vitePreprocess } from '@sveltejs/kit/vite';

const dev = process.argv.includes('dev');

/** @type {import('@sveltejs/kit').Config} */
const config = {
    preprocess: vitePreprocess(),

    kit: {
        adapter: adapter({
            pages: 'build',
            assets: 'build',
            fallback: undefined,
            precompress: false,
            strict: true
        }),
        paths: {
            base: dev ? '' : process.env.BASE_PATH,
        }
    }
};

export default config;
```

finally, I copied the deploy script from the Svelte documentation, set up the deployment from GitHub actions and I have my static website.

Now I'd like to have a dynamic route that shows different content based on the data I have on my db.

So I created the */[book]/[chapter]/+page.svelte* page.

As long as Svelte can detect a static link to the dynamic page route in another page (e.g. `<a href="{base}/fahrenheit-451/1">Fahrenheit 451</a>`) everything works fine.

However, if the link to that page is dynamic (e.g. I get the data from my db and I create the link based on that) once I get to the page if I refresh the page I get a 404 file not found error.

Reading Svelte's documentation, the only solution I found is to use [entries](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/page-options#entries).

The downside is, if I understand correctly, that if the data in my db changes quite often, I will keep having the same issue on new and modified pages.

Is there a better solution to this problem or am I forced to use another adapter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are supposed to use the `fallback` option of the adapter for dynamic routes; set it to `'404.html'`. (Not sure how well it can coexist with static routes, though. [The docs](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/adapter-static#options-fallback) state that it is for SPA mode.)

The file will be returned by GitHub pages if no static file exists and SvelteKit will determine the route/parameters and load/execute the correct JS code.